# User Removed, and I lost 590 points!

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

A user was removed, and I lost 590 rep points!

The reason that this question got asked again, is I still don't understand why us (other) users get penalized because some user got removed. Their votes, up or down, counted when they were cast, and when the user was still active on this system. I don't need a big dialog here, but mostly to **let SE know that I don't think this policy is fair to the rest of us**.

Comment: -68 for me. That, unfortunately, is how things are.

Comment: Just -10 for me, but you have many more questions and answers than I do. These things happen.

Comment: I guess you could go through your content and see which users you responded to now have something like  `user.....` (where the dots are numbers) in plain text and not a clickable link as their username.

Comment: Tsk stop complaining. I lost 680. It is a conspiracy: Oli lost 0 :(

Comment: I won 2 rep point instead of losing some x)

Comment: I'm closing this question as duplicate of the one you asked last time you lost a couple points when another user was removed. The answer stays the same and will always stay the same: it's not something we as other users or moderators can influence or have any business in. We don't need to debate it every time.

Comment: The reason that this question got asked again, is I still don't understand why us (other) users get penalized because some user got removed. Their votes, up or down, counted when they were cast, and when the user was still active on this system. I don't need a big dialog here, but mostly to let SE know that I don't think this policy is fair to the rest of us.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, 590 points is just 59 upvotes.  Since you have posted 44 questions and 1,577 answers on the main site so far, that doesn't seem to be an excessive number.

It seems I only lost 10 points when this user was removed, but then I've posted far fewer questions and answers than you have.

Comment: I see it as a betrayal of my trust in creating good answers. Even if the user abused the system it does not mean his upvotes or downvotes are wrong >:-D

Comment: @Rinzwind The fact that a user was removed doesn't mean that they abused the system. They may just have asked for their account to be deleted.

Comment: That's even worse. In that case the name should just be renamed to an id instead of a name and the rep should be kept.

Comment: @Rinzwind Perhaps that's something you might suggest on [Meta:SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)?